# Adding Shortcut Keys in an Image via google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

I need help in placing a set of codes in my image button to help me log the time each time I click it. The shortcut keys that I want to add is "crtl+shift+:". Is this possible in google sheets? I hope someone could help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible with shortcut Keys but you can assign a script to an image in Google Sheets. Here is the snippet I created:

```
function createTimeStamp() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('FILE_ID');

      var range = sheet.getLastRow(); //Get Last Row with Data
      var datas = sheet.getSheets()[0];
      var startRow = range + 1;  // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process

      var dataRange = datas.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows);

      var data = dataRange.getValues();
        var newTimestamp = timestamp();
          datas.getRange(startRow, 1).setValue(newTimestamp);


}

function timestamp() {
  var timezone = "GMT-5";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
  return newDate;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Hope this helps.